# How do I start apache in OSX Mountain Lion / Mavericks?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, osx-mountain-lion, osx-mavericks

OSX Mountain Lion removed the GUI for web sharing, but apache is still installed.

How do I start and stop the service?  How do I get the service to automatically launch on startup?

Comment: Its starts automatically, at least for me. Just type 0.0.0.0 it should  be there.

Comment: @Lri No. I did upgrade from 10.7

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The LaunchDaemon for Apache is still there as well, so all you have to do it load it:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

The `-w` makes it permanent, i.e. it'll be reloaded when you reboot.

Comment: How do you turn this off once it's started this way?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon: `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`

Comment: Hmm, something is still running on localhost, I had assumed it was Apache, maybe I have something else running.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon: You can use e.g. `sudo lsof -i:80` to see what process is listening on a given port.  From there, [this previous answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/285078/how-can-i-prevent-a-process-from-running-under-mac-osx-10-6/285088#285088) might help you track it down...

Answer (score 35):

**Terminal Commands**

Starting: "sudo apachectl start"

Stopping: "sudo apachectl stop"

Restarting: "sudo apachectl restart"

**Launching on Startup**

(See the marked answer in this thread)

Comment: Is there an equivalent ShutdownItems dir? Don't have OSX in front of me at the moment...

Comment: There used to be /etc/rc.shutdown.local -- not sure if that is still around...

Answer (score 12):

`sudo apachectl start` also enables the launchd daemon. It overrides the `Disabled` key in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` by modifying `/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist`, just like `launchctl load -w`.

For `http://localhost/~username/` to work, you have to create
`/etc/apache2/users/username.conf` and add a `<Directory>` directive like
this:

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
Options Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: I found a really great writeup of this, here.  Also covers php module enablation.  http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion

Answer (score 8):

Slifty and Lauri hint at an important concept without clearly saying it.

"sudo apachectl start" will not only start apache but will also modify /private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist so that apache will automatically restart each time the system is rebooted.

Similarly, "sudo apachectl stop" will stop apache and modify the above file so that apache won't start when the system is rebooted.

This seems to be the simplest way to control whether the service starts automatically.

Answer (score 3):

For those in search of a GUI, Click On Tyler has developed a control panel app, http://clickontyler.com/blog/2012/02/web-sharing-mountain-lion/

[image: GUI sample]

Comment: Nice widget.. however in my system something went wrong and apache is not starting..:(

Comment: Same here. Seems to be a little bit sloppy coded - good old confusion about the .pid-file I guess ...zzz

Comment: This is cool.. But outdated, doesn't work on Yosemite. How do we remove this from our settings pane?

Comment: To Delete: `~/Library/PreferencePanes`

Comment: Sorry, this is no longer available, or became part of a commercial product that you can only download complete - not just the preference panel. Any alternatives?

Comment: Honestly better to use `ngnix` at this point.

Answer (score 1):

This preference pane has the links for computer site folder and to open a browser : http://stowlake.com/WebServer

Comment: This rather ugly UI's preference panel crashes immediately as you try to start the web-server on both OS-X 10.11 and 10.12. Crash-logs available at your request ;)