# How can I start an custom installed apache at boot in OSX

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

I had to install a custom Apache on OSX because I needed a very specific configuration for a client and I could not make the default one work correctly with it, unfortunately.

So, I saw how to start in manually, using *apachectl* binary:

```
sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
```

And I also saw I can make the default Apache start with a [*launchctl* command](https://superuser.com/questions/455505/how-do-i-start-apache-in-osx-mountain-lion).

But, **how could I make a custom installed to start at boot**, instead of the default one? If it's possible, I would like to use system's *launchctl*.

Comment: Thanks. Added the solution above and marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution:

Unload default Apache:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

Create a LaunchDaemon file ( `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.aaa.launchd.apache2.plist` ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.aaa.launchd.apache2</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl</string>
    <string>start</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Change file owner:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.aaa.launchd.apache2.plist
```

And, finally, add it to be loaded on boot:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.aaa.launchd.apache2.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

You would do the same as the launchctl procedure you linked to.  The missing piece is that you need to make your own launchd.plist and save it in the LaunchDaemons/ directory.  `man launchd.plist` for information on the plist format; or, you can probably copy the original apache one and change the path to suit your needs.

Comment: Save your own (or copied) plist-file in /Library/LaunchDaemons. And dont forget to either disable the systems httpd-plist or use a different port in your custom httpd.conf otherwise both webservers try to use the same port. And you will have to adapt the apachectl-file when you want to use it to start your own apache.